# Constructing a Walsh diagram of AH2

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, erratum

According to Wikipedia, for the $\ce{AH2}$ Walsh diagram:

[image]

and the Walsh diagram in Shriver and Atkins *Inorganic Chemistry*, the $a_1$ orbital sinks in energy going from 90 to 180°. Furthermore, the $b_2$ orbital at 90° is higher in energy than the $a_1$ (lone pair).

However according to the second, newer diagram for a AH2 molecule on the same page:

[image]

the $a_1$ is rises in energy and the $b_2$ is definitely lower in energy than  the $a_2$ (or $a_1$ lone pair). This matches also my own self-made diagram, using Hartree-Fock 6-31G*, calculated through Spartan. Other pages use the same Walsh diagram.

What is going on here?

Shrivers textbook explains the rise of the $a_1$ orbital through decreased H-H overlap and reduced involvement of the $\ce{X~2_{pz}}$.

Comment: Just fyi for passers-by, here's the diagram in the 5th edition of Shriver & Atkins: http://i.imgur.com/VTcN1up.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I'd say the diagram from Atkins "Inorganic Chemistry" is in error.**

I went to what I consider the "definitive source" for such Walsh diagrams: [*Orbital Interactions in Chemistry* by Albright, Burdett and Whangbo](https://books.google.com/books?id=HaFNl7oWDM0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Orbital+Interactions+in+Chemistry&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyldDwvYHKAhUIjz4KHdooB5cQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Orbital%20Interactions%20in%20Chemistry&f=false).

Here's their diagram for $\ce{H2S}$ (the linear on the left, the bent on the right):

[image]

They don't readily indicate the method they used for the calculation, but on this energy scale the difference between the $1\sigma_g$ and $1a_1$ is minimal. They show that the $1a_1$ is lower in energy since the interaction with the central p orbital will be stabilizing.

As to the $1b_2$ rising above the $2a_1$ in the bent structure -- the diagram from Albright, Burdett, and Whangbo agree that there's no "crossing."